# Why are frame pointers saved in the beginning of the main function

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, stack-frame

Assume this C code:

```
int main(){
   return 0;
}
```

Would look like this in assembly:

```
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

I know that Frame pointer `fp` needs to be saved in the start of functions by `pushq   %rbp` since it needs to be restored when returnning to the caller function.

My question is why do so in `main`? what's the parent caller of `main`? Isn't `fp` pointing to a virtual address, meaning when `main` terminates the address doesn't mean anything anymore to the next program, correct?

Are `fp` (or even sp) values persistent between different programs and their address space?

Comment: `main` is called by another function so it needs to return to the other function.

Comment: so how are sp/fp values set when a comply new program is loaded? are its old value re-used or does the loader  reset them?

Comment: @Nic It's implementation-defined behaviour and depends on what operating system and binary format you use.  For example, on modern Linux systems, `rbp` starts out zeroed out while `rsp` points to the first free address on the stack above which some useful data is found (arguments, environment, ELF aux vector).  That address is random every time you start the program.

Comment: Using rbp as a frame pointer is optional with most compilers. If frame pointers are omitted, then rbp is freed up to be used as a general purpose register. There is a legacy issue with using bp to access stack variables on an 8086, because sp can't be used as a base register on 8086, so in that case, bp is normally to access stack based variables

Comment: Turn on optimizations in your compiler, and you'll see those instructions go away, e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/Nr1hP2

Comment: @fuz: In the x86-64 System V ABI, the process startup state has RSP pointing to `argc` on the stack, not free space below it.  But yes, it's all documented in the ABI, and argv[] and envp[] are above that.

Comment: If you compile with "-O2", you'll have a `main` body with something like: `xorl %eax, %eax; ret`, that does away with the stack frame. In fact, modern debuggers don't even need a frame pointer register, and can typically perform debugging with [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug info if enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what's the parent caller of main?

In linux `main` is called by `__libc_start_main` witch in term is called by `_start`, in windows I'm not so sure but there is also a `_start`.

In fact a neat trick is to start a C program without `main`:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

void _start() 
{  
    printf("No main function!\n");
    exit(0); 
}
```

compile with:

```
gcc main.c -nostartfiles
```

For Windows(10, gcc 8.1.0) and Ubuntu(18.04, gcc 9.2.0)

```
clang -Wl,-e,-Wl,__start main.c
```

For MacOS (10.14.6, Xcode 11.3)

Here is an article that talks about [Linux x86 Program Start Up](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html)

Comment: Note that providing your own `_start` may cause the libc to not be initialised correctly.  Don't do this unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @fuz, yes, you are correct, this is just a small sample to ilustrate that `main()` is not the beginning of a program startup. The article illustrates your point.